# AngularJS How to take functions out of controllers and put in a factory

Tags: angularjs

Ok to continue with my understanding of Angular factories. I am trying to remove functions out of my bloated controllers and put into factories. I have an "OrderFormController" that holds all my functions for the entire app. What I am trying to do is create a factory that holds all these functions and call the needed function in a particular view through its view controller. This is where I am in the process, but I cannot get it to work..

Here is the OrderFormController that as of now holds all the functions

```
app.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope) {

$scope.toggleActive = function(s){
    s.active = !s.active;
    s.qty = 1;
};

$scope.add = function(s){
    if (s.active){
        s.qty+= 1;
    }
};

$scope.minus = function(s){
    if (s.qty != 1){
        s.qty-= 1;
    }
};

$scope.clearCart = function(){

    angular.forEach($scope.items.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            s.active = false;
            s.qty = 1;
        }
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.foods, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            s.active = false;
            s.qty = 1;
        }
    });
};

$scope.total = function(){

    var total = 0;
    var dtotal = 0;
    var ftotal = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.items.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            dtotal+= s.qty * s.price;
        }
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.options.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            ftotal+= s.price;
        }
    });
    total = dtotal + ftotal;

    return total;
};

$scope.totalItems = function(){

    var totalItems = "";
    var dtotalItems = "";
    var ftotalItems = "";

    angular.forEach($scope.items.results, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            dtotalItems+= s.name+" $"+s.price+".00 Qty: "+s.qty+" , ";
        }
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.foods, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            ftotalItems+= s.name+" $"+s.price+".00 Qty: "+s.qty+" , ";
        }
    });
    totalItems = dtotalItems + ftotalItems;

    return totalItems;
};
});
```

this is my factory or atleast the first function

```
app.factory('OrderData', function() {
var OrderFactory = {};

OrderFactory.toggleActive = function(item){
    item.active = !item.active;
    item.qty = 1;
};

return OrderFactory;

});
```

here is the MenuController where I am trying to call this function

```
app.controller('MenuController', function($scope, OrderData) {

$scope.toggle = OrderFactory.toggleActive(item);

});
```

and this is being called by

```
ng-click="toggle(item)"
```

any help would be apprieciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it up like this instead:

```
app.controller('MenuController', function($scope, OrderData) {

$scope.toggle = OrderData.toggleActive;
```

This is making it so that the .toggle function is the same as the toggleActive function. In your example it's running the toggleActive function right away.

Sidenote: you have OrderData and OrderFactory, which one is it?

Comment: well doesn't the toggleActive function require a value to toggle?? it works but as above i am lost as to why this is working without passing a value to toggle in the controller...

Comment: It will get passed in automatically as that's how javascript works. As long as you call toggle with an item, it will call toggleActive with the item.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation... i guess i will just have to get used to doing it like this... i will accept this answer as correct although both answers are right...but you posted first so... anyway thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2):

Your service is named `OrderData`, but you're using an undefined `OrderFactory` variable to call it.

BTW, when you're doing

```
app.factory('OrderData', function() {
    ...
```

You're defining a *service* named OrderData. The factory is the anonymous function that *creates* and returns the service. OrderData is a *service*.

See also [Mathew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926984/571407) regarding how to expose a method of the service in the scope.

Comment: ok it does work, and both answers are correct, however i am curious as to way i do not need to pass a value in the controller....

Comment: If you pass a value, you call the function OrderData.toggleActive() with an undefined variable as argument, and store the value returned by the function call into $scope.toggle. What you want is not that. What you want is to add the function toggleActive to the scope.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... with the help from you guys i have been able to add all my math functions... i now am working on adding the total function which is using ForEach to go through the data.. I think its best to start a new post as this question has been answered correctly several times...thanks for your time and the explanation